# Using different C++ templates for different levels of tree

Tags: c++, oop, templates, tree

I have a tree with the following requirement

```
T
|_T
| |_T
|   |_Y
|
|_T
  |_T
    |_Y
```

Here T and Y are two different template types. I need to use templates as I need to support other more generic operations on all nodes.

Can someone help me out .

As of now my tree node looks like this

```
template <typename T> class HierarchicalItem {
private:
    int32_t id;
    shared_ptr<T> data;
    shared_ptr<FlatList<HierarchicalItem<T> > > children;
}
```

But the above can only support a single template type.

Here, T is simple value object with getters and setters. The same applies for Y. However both T and Y are different from each other and not related. Typically both T and Y will be read from an input stream and populated in the tree.

Both T and Y have == , = , <<, !=, < operators overloaded and both define no-arg constructors.

Also different type Y is only needed for leaf nodes, however I feel that design should accomodate if possible any number of different types.

One more piece of information, both T and Y are auto-generated files and I would ideally not like to touch the source code of both.

Comment: you might want to take a look at the [Boost Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/) library

Comment: Yes, as of now Y is always leaf.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit both templates from a common base class. Since you already have a pointer-based tree, I infer you're not going for compile-time-only solutions, and in this case inheritance with dynamic casts suffices.

Something like this could work:

```
class TreeNodeBase {
protected: // or public?
    int32_t id;
    FlatList<TreeNodeBase> children;
}

template <typename T>
class HierarchicalItem : public TreeNodeBase { // or protected?
    shared_ptr<T> data;
}
```

To read the data back, downcast the item:

```
...
TreeNodeBase n = children.First(); // for example
HierarchicalItem<SomePayloadType> p = dynamic_cast<HierarchicalItem<SomePayloadType> >(n);

if (!p) { /* handle wrong payload type */ } else { /* use p.data */ }
```

Quite cumbersome so far, but it's impossible to tell optimal design details while not seeing the whole picture, so, hope you get the idea.

Comment: I am a newbee to C++ and templates. It will help if could share some code snippets for the same.

Comment: @sharadendusinha To produce a useful example one also has to know about the payload you intend to put into this structure, especially if T varies from node to node or stays the same. Please elaborate the question so that we could go further :)

Comment: added more details, hope it helps. If you need more info let me know.

Comment: I will try and let you know, but I think youve given me a solution.